# how to stop vim suspending when using gx

Tags: netrw, linux

When I press <kbd>gx</kbd> over a link in vim, it opens it in an external application, when it does this it also suspends Vim.

How do I prevent it from suspending Vim, so that I can use Vim while browsing whatever it opened externally.

Comment: Can you specify your OS, Vim version? It does not suspend here (OSX, MacVim 8.0)

Comment: Using GVim on Windows, I do not have this problem. However, at the bottom, vim says, "Press <cr> to continue," which is just Enter. Using terminal vim in MinGW (I know, all bets are off), it doesn't open a web page, but still doesn't freeze.

Comment: Debian Jessie 8.4.0, Vim 7.4. Hm... mine seems to be a bit iffy, if it opens it will suspend vim, if it doesn't it will not suspend.

Comment: Vim 8 with Fedora 25 here, works by default without suspending.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vim-shell](https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell) plugin instead with this config:

```
let g:netrw_nogx = 1 " disable netrw's gx mapping.
nnoremap gx :Open<CR>
```

Comment: Another alternative might be my [xdg_open.vim](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/xdg_open.vim) plugin.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, :Open is still blocking vim. I use NVIM v0.2.2 on lubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

What works for me with neovim v0.2.2 on lubuntu 17.10 is the open-browser.vim plugin (https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim) with the following settings in my `init.vim`.

```
let g:netrw_nogx = 1 " disable netrw's gx mapping.
    nmap gx <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
vmap gx <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I wrote my own function for it.
(Thanks to the guy below who had a way to do it without having to use the registry. I modified my own with this.)

The strategy is to store the url under the Vim-cursor to a variable

```
let url = expand('<cWORD>')
```

and then use bash to open firefox with the url as argument:

```
call feedkeys(':!bash firefox ' . url . ' &' . "\<CR>\<ESC>" )
```

The `&` is used to open firefox in the background, and the `\<CR>\<ESC>` is to enter the command and escape the message box that it prompts.

We put this into a function that we call `OpenURL()` and then remap `gx` to run that function.

```
nnoremap gx :call OpenURL()<CR>
```

The `<CR>` is again to actually execute the command.

In total it looks like this:

```
function! OpenURL()
    let url = expand('<cWORD>')
    call feedkeys(':!bash firefox ' . url . ' &' . "\<CR>\<ESC>" )
endfunction

nnoremap gx :call OpenURL()<CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would benefit greatly from an [edit] describing how the code works. (PS you can save/restore registers; combined with a try/catch, you could make sure not to lose whatever is already saved in `@a`, if you were interested. But you can skip registers entirely: `let url = expand('<cWORD>')`.)